# Не могу записать в переменную значение атрубута <img>

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,
я только изучаю JS, но появилась идея и хочу добить до ее до конца

Задача:

```
<img src="../images/6.jpg" alt="" id="pic" widht="150" height="150">
```

достать атрибут widht и записать в переменную

```
var i = document.getElementById('pic').width;
```

выдает ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотите получить значение с атрибута `width`, а атрибут у вас `widht`.
Получение значения атрибута и запись его в переменную ниже

```js
var i = document.getElementById('pic').getAttribute('widht'); //ищем в документе элемент с id="pic" и получаем значение атрибута widht
alert(i); //проверяем или все получилось
```

```html
<img src="../images/6.jpg" alt="" id="pic" widht="150" height="150">
```

Comment: Автор вопроса неправильно написал, а вы подхватили именно ошибочный вариант... Никакого widht в природе не существует, в коде у автора как раз правильно было написано. А ошибка ни в этом, а в отсутствии style.

Comment: @Александр, вы не правы, добавление _style_ никак не поможет в этом случае